# Blender 2.8 - Export to FBX not available?

Tags: blender

I have started using the ALPHA 2 Build of BLENDER 2.8
I created a model and rig with some animation 'actions' that I would like to export to FBX for use in UNITY 3D.

How can i export to FBX in Blender 2.8 alpha 2?
I enabled the ADD ON but there is no such Export As option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender 2.80 is currently under development, it is undergoing large changes. Some of these changes include the python API, which will lead to the python addons needing adjustments to work with the new version. The python API changes have not been finalised yet, the API will be finalised one month before the stable release, right now that would appear to be in the next two or three months.

The current builds of 2.80 save blend files that previous versions do not completely read. While 2.79 initially appears to fail opening a 2.80 blend file, the data can be found it just isn't linked to the current scene. Some manual fiddling or python usage can make the data available in 2.79.

At this stage 2.80 has two import/export options, collada and alembic, both of these are C/C++ code based which is why they have not broken with the python changes. I'm not sure if unity can import a collada file, if it can't then you can import the collada file into blender 2.79 to export it as fbx.